# Is it possible to restrict access to ActiveAdmin collection_action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, cancan

I want to restrict access to ActiveAdmin `collection_action`. Is it possible to do it somehow?

I need something like this:

```rb
collection_action :send_emails, method: :post, if: proc { authorized? }
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, you can use their standard Authorization Adapter https://activeadmin.info/13-authorization-adapter.html